# Test correct sorting of array using another array in Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

My application needs some arbitrary sorting of an object array.

This is a simplified version of the code I came up with:

The object:

```java
public class MyObject {
    Integer number;
    String name;
    // Getters and setters
```

Now, the *number* Integer is actually one of X numbers in an enum.

The function:

```java
private List<MyObject> sort(List<MyObject> toSort, List<Integer> order){
    toSort.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> order.indexOf(o.getNumber())));
    return toSort;
}
```

So, I chucked everything in a simple app just to test out this function:

[You can try it for yourselves](http://tpcg.io/CZMP9pep)

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    Application app = new Application();

    List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    myObjects.add(new MyObject(1, "IN"));
    myObjects.add(new MyObject(2, "THESE"));
    myObjects.add(new MyObject(3, "ORDER"));
    myObjects.add(new MyObject(4, "RANDOM"));
    myObjects.add(new MyObject(5, "ARE"));
    myObjects.add(new MyObject(6, "COMPLETELY"));

    List<Integer> defaultOrder = Arrays.asList(2,5,1,6,4,3);

    app.sort(myObjects, defaultOrder).stream().map(MyObject::getName).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

So far, so good. This produces the desired result since this prints out:

```
THESE
ARE
IN
COMPLETELY
RANDOM
ORDER
```

But I'm stuck with the testing of this.

How can I set up a test such that something like this happens:

```java
@Test
void Given_TheLists_When_ArbitrarilySorting_Then_GetExpectedResults(){
    List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<>(); 
    //The actual objects are pulled from the database (I can mock that),
    //But the idea is that this applies to any list of myObjects (remember the enum)

    List<Integer> defaultOrder = Arrays.asList(5,3,6,2,4,1); //This has the same size as the enum

    magicAssertion(app.sort(myObjects, defaultOrder)).someMagicalStream()...etc);
}
```

By **magicAssertion**  and **someMagicalStream** I mean that I go through the result of my function with the sorting array I provided again and ensure that the order is correct.
I suspect there's a stream casually mocking me from the java docs.

P.D.: Could I have figured this out with the time it took me to write this post? mmm, probably not.

Comment: You could provide the test data and your expected output as input to your test method. After calling the sorting function, then validate the actual output against the expected output. Isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the algorithm (in Java 8) to perform that validation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no need to return in the below method:

```java
private void sort(List<MyObject> toSort, List<Integer> order){
    toSort.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> order.indexOf(o.getNumber())));
}
```

Assuming you are using `junit`, you can use the `Assert` class methods. `Assert.assertArrayEquals(expectedList.toArray(), actualOutputList.toArray())` or you could try any testing libraries like `testng` which has assert methods to validate a collection.

```java
@Test
void Given_TheLists_When_ArbitrarilySorting_Then_GetExpectedResults(){
    List<MyObject> myObjects = mockData(); 
    List<Integer> defaultOrder = Arrays.asList(5,3,6,2,4,1);
    List<MyObject> expectedObjects = //.. list of objects in expected order.

    app.sort(myObjects, defaultOrder);
    // myObjects are now sorted. Validate against the expected list.
    
    org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals(expectedObjects.toArray(), myObjects.toArray());

    // If you are using testNG
    org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(myObjects, expectedObjects);
}
```